# MPI_SendRecv Timing

Tags: c, mpi, openmpi

When I use the following code by changing the different buffer sizes, I always get the similar time (around 0.5s) for the API call of `MPI_SendRecv` no matter how large I set the `Dim`,

> **is there something wrong with the timing method for MPI call?**
> or 
> **is it the Asynchronization (return immediately after the call) of the MPI API call?**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <mpi.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    float *d_msg;

    if (argc < 3){
        printf("./exe ndevices Dim\n");
        exit(-1);
    }

    int myrank, tag=0;
    MPI_Status status;

    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &myrank);
    if (myrank == 0)
        printf("\n\n===== MPI Start =====\n");
        
    const int num_GPUs = 2;
    const int Dim = 100;

    cudaMalloc((void**)&d_msg, Dim*sizeof(float)); 

    double t1, t2; 
    t1 = MPI_Wtime(); 

    MPI_Sendrecv(d_msg, Dim, MPI_FLOAT, (myrank + 1)%num_GPUs, tag, d_msg, Dim, MPI_FLOAT, (myrank - 1 + num_GPUs)%num_GPUs, tag, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);

    t2 = MPI_Wtime(); 
    printf( "Elapsed time is %f\n", t2 - t1 ); 

    MPI_Finalize();
    printf("--*-- MPI Rank: %d END--*--\n", myrank);


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: That's probably waiting time. Put an `MPI_Barrier` call before measuring `t1`.

Comment: On some MPI implementations, some setup is performed during the very first communication, so you are likely measuring this overhead here. The proper way to benchmark is to run several warmup iterations, and then not only one but several `MPI_Sendrecv()` (enough to take much longer than the `MPI_Wtick()` timer resolution.